# Sample continuity of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I wanted to know if the Brownian motion and the fractional Brownian motion are almost surely
sample continuous or not?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's part of the definition.

Comment: what definition are you talking about, the one of the Brownian motion or the fractional Brownian motion or both?

Comment: You have to take continuity as part of the definition of both.  There are measurability issues which prevent one from asking about the probability that a function is continuous unless you build the function to be continuous by hand.  For both regular and fractional Brownian motion, you can use Kolmogorov's Continuity Theorem to show that a continuous version exists and then we define that version to be the (fractional) Brownian motion.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian In many constructions, continuity is not part of the definition of Brownian motion. Rather, one *shows* it.

Comment: @Did I would say one shows that there is an equivalent process which is built by hand to be pathwise continuous, which is meaningfully different. Take a continuous Brownian Motion $B(t)(\omega)$ and consider the process $B(t)(\omega)1_{B(t)(\omega)\text{ is irrational} }.$  It is not hard to check that this satisfies the other conditions of the standard definitions of Brownian Motion, but is almost surely pathwise almost everywhere discontinuous. The event that a stochastic process is continuous (even at a point) is not measurable unless one works on a sample space where one assumes continuity

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian As I said, almost sure path continuity must be *shown* somehow, one cannot just define Brownian motion, say, as a path continuous process with such-and-such marginals, because such a process could be impossible.

Comment: @Did Indeed, one should also check that it is possible to define a process with such-and-such marginals.  There are circumstances where the extension theorem fails, after all.  Whether or not the definition makes sense is another question entirely.  My point is that continuity is part of the definition and if you do not include continuity in the definition of Brownian motion, you cannot prove continuity from the other parts of the definition. The statement that all Gaussian processes with the same marginals as Brownian motion are continuous is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths of a fractional Brownian motion are (a.s.) locally Hölder continuous of any order $\gamma<H$ where $H$ denotes the Hurst index. In particular, the sample paths are continuous. The Hölder continuity follows from the Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257904/holder-continuity-of-fractional-brownian-motion).